# How Many Numbers Are In A BigQuery Field That Is A String

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to simply count how many numbers are in a string inside BigQuery.

I can obviously count how long the string is using LENGTH():

```sql
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT 'h0w many numb3rs?';
SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS length;
```

But how do I count how many numbers are in the string?

Comment: Note to self:

`WITH temp AS (
  SELECT 'h0w many numb3rs?' AS str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'and th1s?' AS str
)
SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS length,
  COUNT(*) AS numbers
FROM temp
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(temp.str, '')) AS char WHERE char BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
GROUP BY str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you guys got me :o)
Joining this thread with below simple and **cheap** option

```
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT 'h0w many numb3rs?';
SELECT str, LENGTH(str) length, COUNT(*) digits
FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str, '')) char
WHERE char BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!! Your answers are always so elegant but always over my head at first.

I cannot edit your answer, but can you please add this solution to the "Alternative setup":

WITH temp AS (
  SELECT 'h0w many numb3rs?' AS str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'and th1s?' AS str
)
SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS length,
  COUNT(*) AS numbers
FROM temp
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(temp.str, '')) AS char WHERE char BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
GROUP BY str

Comment: oh, and why is it "cheaper" to do a JOIN to an UNNEST than simply to do what Scott B or Logan suggested?

Comment: why cheaper? - because of eliminating use of expensive regexp functions :o)

Comment: `can you please add this solution to the "Alternative setup"` - her on SO, it is not appreciated when question is changed especially when answers already provided! I don't want to change my already given answer - but if you post your new question - i will be happy to answer it

Comment: Understood! I take back the request, then. Let's just leave it in the comments. I really just wanted a record of the way to do that as a JOIN. I am fine with just looking for it in the comments. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 1):

Extract only numeric values from the string using regex and count them

```
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT 'h0w many numb3rs?';
SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS length, array_length(regexp_extract_all(str, r'[\d]'))
```

[image]

reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length

Answer (score 1):

You may consider below approach wherein you can directly count the length of the numbers from `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

```sql
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT 'h0w many numb3rs?';
SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS length,
  LENGTH(regexp_replace(str, r'[^0-9]', '')) as total_numbers
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to remove numbers (by replacing numbers with empty strings using REGEXP_REPLACE) and then find the difference in the original string length and the reduced string length. Search the [re2 documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) for available regex syntax. You can use the Perl shorthand `[\d]` for digits (or `[0-9]` works too).

```sql
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT 'h0w many numb3rs?';
SELECT
  str,
  LENGTH(str) AS length,
  LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'[\d]', '')) AS numbers,
  LENGTH(str) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'[[:alpha:]]', '')) AS non_alpha_characters;
```

(note: you can find the non-alpha characters (including spaces and punctuation) by matching and removing `[[:alpha:]]` (or equivalently `[A-Za-z]`) characters.